# Jython 2.7.0 "Final Release" on Windows - difficulty including jars

Tags: command-line, jython, executable-jar, jython-2.7

I have a few projects which run using Jython 2.7b1 where I add the jars (in fact all the jars in a directory) by doing this:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;"%SYSADMIN%\resources\java jar files/*"
set JYTHONPATH=...
C:\jython2.7b1\jython myproj\__main__.py
```

But my latest project is using 2.7.0FR and this "set CLASSPATH" approach doesn't seem to work.  I then tried this:

```
D:\apps\jython2.7.0\bin\jython -Dpython.path="%SYSADMIN%\resources\java jar files/*" my_latest_proj\__main__.py
```

... but it didn't work.  Then I wanted to see whether I could load an individual .jar:

```
D:\apps\jython2.7.0\bin\jython -Dpython.path="%SYSADMIN%\resources\java jar files\lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.0.jar" my_latest_proj\__main__.py
```

This didn't work either: the following line

```
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr import FrenchAnalyzer
```

leads to the following error: "No module named apache"... nor is there any "unpacking" of the jar as you typically see with Jython the first time you use a jar.

Finally I tried this:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;"%SYSADMIN%\resources\java jar files\lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.0.jar"
```

... same thing: "No module named apache"

NB I have no trouble getting jars to work from within my project when running it under Eclipse.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha...!

1) It ***appears*** that with Jython2.7.0FR you have to use **forward slashes** in paths in the CLASSPATH, even in a Windows OS. This appears to be a change relative to 2.7b1...

2) I also seem to find that **paths with spaces** are to be avoided... previously I could enclose such a path in quotes and it would work OK.  This seems not to work any more.

Any comments from the Jython "High Command" would be welcome...